# Routing with index.php where I define constant

Tags: php, routes, include, constants

As another user suggested me in another question, an advanced approach is to use

> FallbackResource or RewriteRule in your .htaccess file to handle all URLs via a single index.php file in the root, then parse $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] to determine from there what code to load and which response to serve.

And then `include './includes/globals.php';` where I set my constant only on index.php, instead of adding it to each file of the site, which can be a long process.

I tried to do that, and the routing part seems to work very well.
Unfortunately the constants I define on `globals.php`, which I include on `index.php` are only defined on `index.php` and not on other scripts.

Where are the errors? How to fix that and any type of advice is much appreciated!

Thank you

`.htaccess` FILE:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

`globals.php`

```
<?php
       define('ROOT', __DIR__)
?>
```

`index.php` FILE (routing file):

```
<?php
include 'globals.php';

$uri = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$trimmeduri = trim($uri, '/');

if($uri == '/'){
    $sigle = $link->query("SELECT sigla AS lingue FROM LINGUE");

    while($lingue_db = mysqli_fetch_array($sigle)){
        $lingue[] = $lingue_db['lingue'];
    }

    $client_lang = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);

    if(in_array($client_lang, $lingue)){
        header("location: http://www.mysite.com/$client_lang/index.php");
    }else{
        header("location: http://www.mysite.com/it/index.php");
    }

}else{
    include "sql.php";
    $link = new mysqli($host, $user, $pw, $db);
    $link->set_charset('UTF8');
    $trimmeduri = $link->real_escape_string($trimmeduri);
    $urlliste = $link->query("SELECT Nome FROM LISTE WHERE URL = '$trimmeduri'");
    while($urllista = mysqli_fetch_array($urlliste)){
        $lista = $urllista['Nome'];
    }
    $uri_count = mysqli_num_rows($urlliste);
    $urlliste->close();

    if($uri_count == '1'){
        header("location: http://www.mysite.com/pages/page.php?name=$lista");
    }elseif($uri_count > '1'){
        header('HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request', true, 400);
        require_once "errors/400badrequest.html";
    }else{
        header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
        require_once "errors/404notfound.php";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: To have constants defined in other scripts, you must include 'globals.php' into these scripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure how you defined your globals.php file but autoloading is something you may want to consider. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php

Infact, I would autoload ALL my classes if I were you, makes life easier in the long run. That is, ofcourse, on the assumption that the files being included are classes.

Comment: I edited my question adding globals.php. I'd like to have this constant avaible on the whole site once included on index.php, but unfortunately it isn't so...

Comment: Right, the pages that are not showing the globals, are they being routed through the index.php file ? The only reason I can see why a page wouldn't register the the globals is because it isn't being routed through the index.php.

Comment: But if you see .htaccess file it is routing all through index.php. And I'm sure that when I load the page I go to index.php and then to /it/index.php. But if I use ROOT on /it/index.php ROOT is not defined... Why?

Comment: Add die() to the globals file, and navigate to the URI that isnt registering the global. If the page doesn't 'die' you know your routing isn;t working. You can then enable rewrite log to check whether the URIs are being routed through the index file. If the constants are set in index.php and all links are routed through index.php then it should show the constant.

Comment: "It dies"... so the constant is defined and the routing is working... But once the constant is defined, is it defined also for other scripts?

Comment: Provided it is on the top of the initial script and all subsequent scripts are included or required in the main script, then yes. See http://pastebin.com/Xvz5tvKU

Comment: Ok, this is the problem... I move to the location with `header('location:page.php')`. Is it recommended to include all the pages instead of moving to them?